# UTF Encoding in selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, utf-8, selenium-webdriver, html-parsing

I currently have the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome()
# request the url and get the page contents
title = result.find("span", {"class": "episode"}).find("a").text
```

However, the 'text' that is returned to me is:

```
# Note the truncation on the word "envol"
<td class="title"><a href="/title/tt1844708/">La grande envol</a></td>
```

However, when I download the page source, it shows the following:

```
<td class="title"><a href="/title/tt1844708/">La grande envolée</a>
    <span class="year_type">(1927)</span><br />
</td>
```

Why is the text truncated in the webdriver response? How would I ensure it gives me the full utf-8 encoded text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are passing the [`page_source`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) contents to `BeautifulSoup` for further parsing.

I would not do that since `selenium` itself can handle the [parsing part](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html) pretty well. For example, you can use [CSS selectors](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.episode a').text
```

Example (using [this `IMDb` page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1844708/)):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1844708/')
>>> print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@itemprop="name"]').text)
La grande envolée
```